# DOCKER ON UBUNTU : failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1):

Tags: docker, gitlab

" write /opt/gitlab/embedded/share/terminfo/n/ntconsole-25-w: no space left on device."

but the strange thing is, space is available in system.

[image]

Comment: You may user `docker system prune` to clean up space, please try.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots of terminal windows or editors into SO questions.  Please do include the minimum code necessary to reproduce your question; it's hard to help based on just an error message, especially when it doesn't especially sound like a programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

clean up space by using

```
docker system prune
```

Clean your system by removing container and images

```
$ docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

This will remove containers

```
$ docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

This will remove the images

Answer (score 0):

1. Where is your docker installation? /usr?
2. Where are your Docker Volume data stored currently? /usr?
3. By default with docker installation the volume data is stored usually on a system directly
4. To change that configure `data-root` in your daemon.json
5. once you change is no need to restart docker, just reload the daemon. `systemctl daemon-reload`
6. in case if you have running containers and do now want to stop them while the deamon reloads, then set up `live-restore` property also in daemon.json and reload the daemon.